# ¿Como llenar un choice field dinámicamente?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

No se como llenar un  `choice` dinámicamente cargándolo mediante una consulta a otro modelo de la base de datos. Es decir, lo que actualmente tengo con lo siguiente_

```
Facultades = (
      ('FACI', (
              ('1', 'Miguel Angel Cedillo Fajardo'),
              ('2', 'Milton Fabian Penaherrera Larena'),
          )
      ),
```

y quiero llenarlo con una consulta algo así:

```
Facultades = (
      ('FACI', (
              ('1', user.object.filter(facultad='faci'),
          )
      ),
```

para que me cargue todos los docentes pertenecientes a esa facultad. ¿De qué manera lo hago?

La idea es que me cargue un listado algo así, pero los nombres extraídos de una consulta :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el modelo completo

```
class Distributivo(models.Model):
  Facultades = (
      ('FACI', (
              ('1', 'Miguel Angel Cedillo Fajardo'),
              ('2', 'Milton Fabian Penaherrera Larena'),
          )
      ),
      ('FACCA', (
              ('1', 'Erika Stefany Gamarra Acuna'),
              ('2', 'Boris Javier Santana Pincay'),
          )
      ),
      ('FACS', (
              ('1', 'Silvia Lissette Pilay Moran'),
              ('2', 'Edison Roberto Portilla Lopez'),
          )
      ),
  )
  Usuario=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True)  
  Docente=models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Facultades)
  dia=models.CharField(max_length=10)
  comienza=models.TimeField(default='00:00')
  termina=models.TimeField(default='00:00')

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.Usuario
```

Comment: Mira el paquete [smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects), tal vez te pueda servir.

Comment: Mejor **Facultades** vuelvelo un Modelo como tal, no un **choices**

Comment: gracias por su respuesta @toledano acabo de revisar el link proporcionado,  no me sirve de mucho.. ya que lo que necesito es solamete q me salga un listado con separadores diciendome donde comienza cada facultad.. similar a la caputura que coloque.. solo que en lugar de llenarla manualmente quiero que se llene mediante una consulta. Espero me pueda ayudar.. Gracias

Comment: Si @castellbot esa es la idea.. que sea un modelo y llenar el choice con la consulta a ese modelo de **Facultades**, es que solo necesito tener separadores dentro del mismo select.. asi como la captura que coloque.. solo que ese choice que llene mediante una consulta en lugar de llenarlo manualmente.. Me puede indicar como hacerlo.. Gracias

Comment: ¿La agrupación es correcta en tu ejemplo? Tienes dos grupos para `FACCA`, ¿no deberían estar juntos?

Comment: @César gracias por tu observacion ya corregi. Fue un error que no me habia percatado... me podrias ayudar con lo que necesito.. Gracias

Comment: ¿El user al que haces referencia es un usuario del sistema?, ¿puedes considerar ese modelo en tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regularmente los choices son para datos con valores muy pequeños y que no cambian, en este caso te aconsejo que usas modelos porque aunque sean pocos datos representan entidades que pueden tener más datos (por ejemplo Docente) y cambiar en un futuro.

```
class Facultad(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField()
    ...

class Docente(models.Model)
    facultad = models.ForeignKey(Facultad, related_name='docentes')
    ...

class Distributivo(model.Model):
    docente=models.ForeignKey(Docente)
    ...
```

Ahora para el listado en tu template debes utilizar algún plugin como [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) que te permita darle estilo a un select o combobox.

Y para el listado de docentes por facultad solamente debes obtener las facultades y usarlo en tu template:

```
facultades = Facultad.objects.all()
```

Y en tu template usarlo en un ciclo donde recorras cada facultad y obtener los docentes relacionados a esta:

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
{% for facultad in facultades %}
  {% for docente in facultad.docentes.all %}
  <option value="{{ docente.facultad.pk }}">docente.name</option>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</select>
```